# Installation of Java is not working on Windows Server 2008 Itanium

Tags: windows, java, windows-server-2008, intel-itanium

When I try to install Java on Windows Server 2008, it gives me the error below. I tried to install JDK 1.5, JDK6 and JDK7 in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Error message:

> The version of the file is not compatible with the version of windows you are running.

I would like to add one more thing, it was Itanium processor server. Please let me know any specific version available for Itanium

How to sort out this issue?

Comment: Show the message for a 32-bit install.

Comment: I updated the processor type.

Comment: Itanium has lost vendor support.  You may want to start considering your hardware upgrade path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>This means, that your Windows Server version is x86 (meaning 32-bit). And you tried to install a 64-bit Java, which wont work.</s>

**Edit:** If this is an Itanium machine, it's quite a different problem. You need to download the Windows Itanium Java 6 installer from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6downloads-1902814.html). There wont be a Java 7 version for it, though.

[From the Oracle blogs:](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/supported_platforms_for_jdk_7)

> Q: What about Linux and Windows on Itanium?
>
> A: Oracle does not plan to
>   port JDK 7 to Windows/Linux Itanium. This is partially due to lack of
>   OS vendor commitments; Microsoft and Red Hat have both stated that
>   they are dropping support for Itanium. However, an OpenJDK port to
>   these platforms is quite feasible as a community project.

Comment: I think he has stated that he tried both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: The way I read the question was, that he tried to install both, but (at least?) one threw an error. And the error message was from the 64-bit installer (You can find the image in the history.)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a Processor mismatch.
I guess the SDK that you would have tried could be for wrong processor type

Comment: Absolutely, you are right. could you please tell me the link for Itanium version of Java download ?

Answer (score 0):

First check if you are running 32 or 64 bit vesrion of OS :
to do so :

1.Press the `WIN+R` keys (Windows key and R). Type the following: `sysdm.cpl`

2.Click on "System Summary": Under "Processor" it will either state "x86" if a 32-bit version of Windows is installed, or "EM64T" if a 64-bit version of Windows is installed

if your OS is X86(32-bit) install X86(32-bit) JDK if not install 64-bit vesrion of JDK

Comment: There is a corner case, where you need to install both: If you are on a x64 System and want to run both x86 Apps that use the plugin (e.g. Firefox) you need to have the x86 JRE too.

Comment: yes I agree, if its a 64-bit machine both 32-bit and 64-bit can be installed.